# Using VLOOKUP to match a user ID to a supervisor

Tags: excel, excel-formula

As you could probably already guess, I am working on a report summary that displays the amount of time each agent has spent in different statuses such as 'Available', 'Unavailable', 'In a meeting', etc. that can easily be modified and doesn't rely on specific criteria, just the table rows & columns. For example, if someone was to switch teams or get a new supervisor, the data would be updated automatically when replacing the supervisor name.

The issue that I am having is when I try to use a VLOOKUP in my 'Report' sheet to match an agent's User ID to their supervisor in the 'Agent List' sheet, I am getting #N/A as my result.

This is the function that I have tried:

**=VLOOKUP('Agent List'!C2, 'Agent List'!A:D, 4, FALSE)**

As far as I know, I have met all the required arguments by stating where the data is stored by using 'Agent List'!, the look up value, the table array, which column to match it to, and whether I want an exact match or approximate match.

I have played around with the function for a while, and have looked at others posts, but was unable to resolve the issue on my own. Any help I can get with this would be great. Any suggestions on a better idea to achieve the same result are also welcome.

Thanks, 
TNA

***Agent List table example:***
[image]

Comment: The controlling column has to be the first or leftmost column. Try index() with match().

Comment: Thank you, Solar Mike. I was able to resolve the issue by using the following function:

=INDEX('Agent List'!$D:$D, MATCH('Agent List'!$D2, 'Agent List'!$D:$D, 0))

Since supervisor was to the right of the the user ID, I was able to use a left index/match.

Comment: Index match can be left middle or right…

Answer (score 0):

#N/A in a vlookup sense usually means the value was no found.

This is due the the data not being in the first column of reference.

Also are you trying to lookup the data from one sheet to another? The value you are looking up should be the first value in the formula. You appear to be looking up from the same table you are returning result from.

Instead you can try:

`=VLOOKUP(OTHERSHEET C2, 'Agent List'!C:D, 2, FALSE)`

OR

`=INDEX('Agent List'!D:D,MATCH(C2,'Agent List'!C:C, 0),1)`